# What do I need to do to assuage R# when it complains about my linear gradient?

Tags: css, resharper, background-image, linear-gradients

I've got this CSS rule:

```
.featured .content-wrapper {
    background-color: #7ac0da;
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0, #a4d4e6 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0, #a4d4e6 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #7ac0da), color-stop(1, #a4d4e6));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0, #a4d4e6 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0, #a4d4e6 100%);
    color: #3e5667;
    padding: 20px 40px 30px 40px;
}
```

...and R# complains about the last background-image line with, `Expected one of: <angle>, to, <named-color>, <system-color>, <color>, rgb(), rgba(), hsl(), hsla().`

I don't know what it wants, though - how do I modify that line to appease the white-gloved mother-in-law that R# sometimes appears to be (don't get me wrong - I love her, anyway)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because that isn't valid CSS. To quote [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient):

> ```
> Formal grammar: 
> linear-gradient(  [ <angle> | to <side-or-corner> ,]? <color-stop> [, <color-stop>]+ )
>                   \---------------------------------/ \----------------------------/
>                     Definition of the gradient line         List of color stops  
>
>                where <side-or-corner> = [left | right] || [top | bottom]
>                  and <color-stop>     = <color> [ <percentage> | <length> ]?
> ```

So you want

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #7ac0da 0, #a4d4e6 100%);
```

See the [history of the syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient#History_of_the_syntax) section for why the vendor-specific versions looks the way they do.

With my R# (7.1), the vendor-specific versions are all hinted `Unknown vendor specific extension 'whatever'`, and their function arguments aren't actually being checked for validity at all.

Comment: So does that mean that *all* of the "left,"s should be converted to "to left,"s?

Comment: @ClayShannon I don't think it's as simple as that (although CSS isn't my #1 area...) I think each of the vendor-specifc extensions can potentially have its own syntax. In fact, I think plain `left`s are right for them, and it was only when the standard was made that they chose to make the syntax unambiguous.